# Android - get max value from sqlite table with condition

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite table like...

```
    id     |    pname    |    ptype    |    amount    
------------------------------------------------------
    1      |     aaaaa   |    qw       |    20    
    2      |     bbbbb   |    qw       |    25    
    3      |     ccccc   |    qw       |    55    
    4      |     aaaaa   |    qw       |    42
```

i want to get output like

```
    id     |    pname    |    ptype    |    amount    
------------------------------------------------------
    1      |     aaaaa   |    qw       |    42    
    2      |     bbbbb   |    qw       |    25    
    3      |     ccccc   |    qw       |    55
```

means non repeative pname with maximum amount...
Which query i should run?

Comment: Hi... i solved like......

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM test1 ORDER BY amount ASC ) GROUP BY pname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later (Android API level 16 or later), you can simply use MAX in the SELECT list, and the other values will be guaranteed to come from the record with the maximum value:

```
SELECT id,
       pname,
       ptype,
       MAX(amount) AS amount
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY pname
```

If you need to work with earlier versions, you need to check explicitly:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MyTable AS smaller
                  WHERE smaller.pname  = MyTable.pname
                    AND smaller.amount < MyTable.amount)
```

Comment: really? `max()` is not available in API<16? I thought, I was using it in some of my apps. :o

Comment: MAX is available in all versions, but the other values are not guaranteed to come from the same record. (Most other SQL databases will raise an error; MySQL allows this but will return random values; that this actually works is an SQLite extension.)

Comment: "other values are not guaranteed to come from the same record" means something like `ptype` might come from a different row?

Comment: Yes, it might come from any record in the group.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query to

- group by `pname`
- put `max(amount) as max_amount` into your projection.

E.g.

```
Cursor c = db.query(table, new String[] {"id", "pname", "ptype", "max(amount) as max_amount"},
        null, null, "pname", null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY amount DESC`